# Type 'AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire

So i am following this course which is using the previous version(4.0) of angularfire2 and I am using the latest version(5.0) and I am having this issue with my code.

An I am getting this error that ***Type 'AngularFireAction>[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.***

```
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
products: Product[];
filteredProducts: any[];
subscription: Subscription;
tableResource: DataTableResource<Product>;
items: Product[];
itemCount: number;

constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
 this.subscription = this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => {
  this.filteredProducts = this.products = products;
  this.initializeTable(products);
 });

}

private initializeTable(products: Product[]){
 this.tableResource = new DataTableResource(products);
  this.tableResource.query({ offset: 0})
    .then(items => this.items = items);
  this.tableResource.count()
    .then(count => this.itemCount = count);
}

reloadItems(params){ 
 if(!this.tableResource) return;
 this.tableResource.query(params)
    .then(items => this.items = items);
}

filter(query: string){
   this.filteredProducts = (query) ?
   this.products.filter(p => 
   p.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
   this.products; 
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}


}
```

Here is the code of product service

```
export class ProductService {

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

create(product){
  return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
}

getAll(){
  return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges(); 
}

get(productId){
  return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
}

update(productId, product){
  return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).update(product);
}

delete(productId){
  return this.db.object('/products/' + productId).remove(); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getAll()` method in your service is returning `snapshotChanges()`. this is an `Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot<{}>>[]>` and you are trying to pass this to `initializeTable(products: Product[])`. That is what the error is saying.

In order to solve this, you need to map the `.snapshotChanges()` to your `Product[]` like so:

```
getAll(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.db.list<Product>('/products')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(changes =>
                changes.map(c => {
                    const data = c.payload.val() as Product;
                    const id = c.payload.key;
                    return { id, ...data };
                })
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: So I did that and it shows this error now The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>' over the map.

Comment: @MohitYadav can you add the imports to you product service in the question? It should be `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: So this error is generated after importing the map operator.

Comment: Wait! That was the issue with some other import statement.This just solved my issue. Thanks Tim Martens.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetAllProducts() : Observable<Product[]>{  returnthis.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().pipe(
    map(changes => 
      changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() as Product }))
    )
  );
  }
```

At first, you should add `GetAll()` like the above, and
you should add the `as Product` interface in your function.